# i am having issues with the download location

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

This Python script does the following:

1. Opens a private (incognito) web browser.
2. Logs into Instagram with a provided username and password.
3. Searches Instagram for profiles related to a specific city (e.g., 'tanger hotel').
4. For each found profile:

   a. Visits the profile page.

   b. Creates a folder on your computer with the profile's name.

   c. Sets the download location to that folder.

   d. Saves basic profile information in a text file.

   e. Scrolls down to load more content on the profile page.

   f. Downloads posts from the profile using an external website (savegram.info).
5. Closes the web browser when done.

In summary, it automates searching Instagram, visiting profiles, and saving their content, organized by creating folders for each profile.

```
type here
import time
import os
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configure Chrome options 
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')

# Create a WebDriver instance with incognito mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

# Wait for the login fields to load
username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))

# Enter your Instagram username and password
username_field.send_keys('otaku5612@gmail.com')
password_field.send_keys('panini15975324')

# Submit the login form
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')))
login_button.click()

# Wait for the login process to complete
time.sleep(5)

# Click the button to open the search bar
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/a/div/div[1]/div/div')))
search_button.click()

# Specify the city you want to search for
city_name = 'tanger hotel'

# Perform a search for profiles related to the specified city
search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input')))
search_bar.send_keys(city_name)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Wait for search results to load
time.sleep(5) 

# Find the profile links from the search results
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Find the profile links from the search results using a CSS selector
profile_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.x1i10hfl.x1qjc9v5.xjbqb8w.xjqpnuy.xa49m3k.xqeqjp1.x2hbi6w.x13fuv20.xu3j5b3.x1q0q8m5.x26u7qi.x972fbf.xcfux6l.x1qhh985.xm0m39n.x9f619.x1ypdohk.xdl72j9.x2lah0s.xe8uvvx.xdj266r.x11i5rnm.xat24cr.x1mh8g0r.x2lwn1j.xeuugli.xexx8yu.x4uap5.x18d9i69.xkhd6sd.x1n2onr6.x16tdsg8.x1hl2dhg.xggy1nq.x1ja2u2z.x1t137rt.x1q0g3np.x87ps6o.x1lku1pv.x1a2a7pz.x1dm5mii.x16mil14.xiojian.x1yutycm.x1lliihq.x193iq5w.xh8yej3')))
# Get the URLs of profile links
profile_urls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in profile_links]

# Loop over each profile
for profile_url in profile_urls:
    driver.get(profile_url)
    # You can add a delay here to give the page some time to load
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Extract the profile name from the URL
    profile_name = profile_url.split('/')[-2]
    
    # Create a folder using the profile name
    profile_folder = os.path.join("c:\\Users\\boda\\Downloads", profile_name)
    os.makedirs(profile_folder, exist_ok=True) 
    
    # Set the download directory to the profile folder
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": profile_folder,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })
    
    # Collect and save profile data in a text file
    profile_data = f"Profile URL: {profile_url}\n"
    profile_data += f"Profile Name: {profile_name}\n"
    profile_data_file_path = os.path.join(profile_folder, "profile_data.txt")
    with open(profile_data_file_path, "w") as profile_data_file:
        profile_data_file.write(profile_data)

    # Scroll to load more content
    last_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    while True:
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
        time.sleep(2)  # Adjust the delay as needed
        new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

   # Find the post links /
    post_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href, "/p/")]')))
    post_urls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in post_links]

    # Visit the third-party website and provide the post URLs for processing
    for post_url in post_urls:
        driver.get('https://savegram.info/')  # Replace with the correct URL of the third-party website

        # Find the input field on the third-party website
        input_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 11).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/form/div/input[1]'))
        )
        
        # Enter the post URL in the input field
        input_field.send_keys(post_url)
        
        # Introduce a random delay to simulate typing behavior
        time.sleep(4)
        
        # Simulate pressing the Enter key to submit the form
        input_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        
        # Wait for the processing to complete
        time.sleep(11)

        # Get the download link from the download wrapper
        download_wrappers = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#div_download > section > div > div > div > div.download-items__btn'))
        )
    
        download_wrappers.click()
        time.sleep(8)

    
    # Return to the search results page after processing each profile
    driver.back()

# Quit the WebDriver instance
driver.quit()
```

i did Sets the download location to that folder but i didnt work

Comment: Maybe do not put your real password in your post? :)

Comment: What is your question? A [mcve] and a clearly stated question would be helpful. (Did you see [ask]?)